# Javascript: XML getElementsByTagName in Safari not return elements

Tags: javascript, xml, safari

Here's part of my XML:

```
<TextLine Version="2" objectID="3" persistentID="6">
    <BaseProperties Version="5">
        <txBase>665.249</txBase>
        <XPos>221.205</XPos>
        <angle>0</angle>
        <verticalText>false</verticalText>
        <objectLeading>0</objectLeading>
    </BaseProperties>
    <EnclosingObjectType>block</EnclosingObjectType>
    <Alignment>center</Alignment>
    <TRString>xfsadxzcsdf</TRString>
    <RunLengthEncodedCharacterAttributes>
        <CharacterAttributes RunCount="13" StyleRef="4098" TextRef="4096" TXKerning="0" TXPostKerning="0" BaselineShifting="0" />
    </RunLengthEncodedCharacterAttributes>
    <tagName></tagName>
</TextLine>
```

And for example I put it in `xmlString`, in Safari:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlObject = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
console.log(xmlObject.getElementsByTagName('TRString')[0].innerHTML);
```

It return error: **TypeError: undefined is not an object**

The I tried:

```
console.log(xmlObject.getElementsByTagName('TRString')[0]);
```

It give you not `#element` but `string`. In this example it should be:

```
<TRString>xfsadxzcsdf</TRString>
```

I don't have this problem in Chrome. I know it's not hard to solve. But I want to know who is more standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does `textContent` in Safari work for you?

if so, you can use `textContent`, when `innerHTML` isn't available...

```
var xmlValue = xmlObject.getElementsByTagName('TRString')[0].innerHTML ||
               xmlObject.getElementsByTagName('TRString')[0].textContent;
```

Comment: Yes. But my question is which one is more standard? `innerHTML` is quite usual. I worry it's non-standard.

Comment: does the edit help? you can also refer to http://quirksmode.org/ for more options

Comment: Thanks and it's helpful. I know it's easy to solve but I also hope my code is maintainable. So I hope to know a standard way to write it. Sorry I'm a little bit obsessive-compulsive.

Comment: that's pretty much standard, unless you use a library. certain things are available in certain browsers. my confusion was over the `html` part. when I use `xml`, I use --> `node.text || node.textContent`...